# Pronunciation of file format GIF

Tags: pronunciation

While browsing the internet I found several cases in which people argue what the correct way to pronounce `.gif` is. There are two sides in this argument:

1. People pronouncing it with a hard **g** as in **gift**. Argument for this is that since it is an acronym for *Graphics Interchange Format* it should be spelled as **g** in the word **graphic**.
2. People pronouncing it with **g** as in **giraffe**. Apparently the creators themselves stated in the documentation for the file that it should be pronounced as **JIF**, as quoted from [Graphic File Formats FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/graphics/fileformats-faq/part1/index.html):

   > Choosy programmers choose "gif" or "jif"?
   >
   > The pronunciation of "GIF" is specified in the GIF specification to be "jif", as in "jiffy", rather than "gif", which most people seem to prefer.

The question is which side is right?

Comment: Oxford English suggests [ɡɪf], see here:
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/gif The reason may be that the g stands for graphic.

Comment: I've been working with websites and web graphics in the UK for 15 years and cannot recall hearing it pronounced as 'jif'. I had no idea that is what the creators intended. Perhaps the pronunciation differs between countries?

Comment: The question makes the false assumption that there is one side that is "right". The whole of the answer is what you said: some people say one and some say the other.

Comment: OP's cited *"[hard G] which most people seem to prefer"* is from a document dated 20Jan97. Firstly, usage may have changed over almost two decades, and secondly that writer may have been unduly influenced by limited *local* knowledge. I rarely hear the hard G form, and I think there's an argument for saying that if the soft G was endorsed by the creators *and* it's the most common version anyway, that's the "correct" version. But it's basically a matter of opinion - **POB**.

Comment: This is a classic case of pronouncing it *toe-may-toe* vs. *toe-mah-toe*.

Comment: Ah, yes. The gif that keeps on giving.

Comment: Perhaps one reason nobody says "jiff" is that "jiffy" is a silly word.

Comment: @Joe: Perhaps [Unilever also think "jif" is a "silly word"](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/personalfinance/comment/4475088/Ad-hoc-Jif-becomes-Cif-in-Unilevers-spring-clean.html) (I've no doubt for some people it has sexual connotations). But maybe they changed it to ***cif*** rather than ***gif*** because they thought most people wouldn't recognise that as implying a change in pronunciation anyway.

Comment: Funny, I actually worked for those dudes! The Jif/Cif thing was just a regional spelling thing.  They tossed a coin and have decided on "cif" everywhere.  (It's extremely difficult handling brand names on a worldwide basis!)  You know, I don't really get the sexual connotation??  Do you mean like "jism" (I think people use that for "ejaculatory fluid")  {Ladies, avert your eyes from this conversation please!}

Comment: The two versions must fight it out in the dog-eat-dog world to see who wins.  Some FAQ page isn't going to shift the balance.  From what I hear the jiffy fellows are being routed.

Comment: changing it to cif would just change it to a fight over hard C and soft C

Comment: @JoeBlow the letter J in Italian is usually pronounced like the letter Y in English, however CIF is pronounced *chif* in Italian, which sounds a lot more like the English pronunciation *JIF*. I seriously doubt that a multinational corporation would toss a coin over something so  important as a product name. But after all you did say [*You often see stunning stupidity on the internet*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205188/pronunciation-of-file-format-gif#comment434223_205188) :) :)

Comment: @JoeBlow It is you who are wrong here. It is "required" that a brand's usage be controlled in order to defend patent and copyright rights.  Respecting this action is not stupid. Regarding product pronunciations as right and wrong is the only reasonable conclusion. Ask Mike Rowe, the guy who lost the right to use his own name for his own company. Pronunciation matters. "Microsoft saw the name as trademark infringement because of its phonetic resemblance to their trademarked corporate name and demanded that he give up the domain." [Linky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_vs._MikeRoweSoft)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format) says:

> The Graphics Interchange Format (better known by its acronym GIF; ***/ˈdʒɪf/*** or ***/ˈɡɪf/***) is a bitmap image format that was introduced by CompuServe in 1987 and has since come into widespread usage on the World Wide Web due to its wide support and portability.

Based on the English pronunciation rule, whenever the letter ***g*** is follower by one of these vowels, ***e***, ***i*** 
, or ***y***, it'll have a ***/dʒ/*** sound, otherwise, it'll sound like ***/g/***. As every other rule, there might be exceptions to this, but in my opinion, if one wants to pronounce this word correctly, ***/ˈdʒɪf/*** will be the correct pronunciation (I myself say ***/ˈɡɪf/*** most of the time!).

P.S. The "*hard **g** sound*" that you mentioned above, is called ***[palatalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization)*** in linguistics, which is not that known to most English speakers.

Comment: re "...whenever the letter g is follower by one of these vowels, e, i , or y, it'll have a /dʒ/ sound" this is true of words that have come from a Romance language, not words of Germanic origin (get, gift, etc) Even so, there are exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the Germanic originated words out @Centaurus. I mentioned there are exceptions to the rule. (: