# What dictates how new words should be pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

Say the word 'libuv', which is a relatively new support library in computer programming.

If I can't find any references on the web as to how it should be pronounced, how do I say it?

And in general is it how the inventor uses it or how the majority sees how it should be pronounced?

Comment: Relevant: [pronunciation of file format "gif"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205188)

Comment: It all depends on how successfully the "inventor" can push his preferred pronunciation. In the end the majority will settle on something.  How the majority arrives at its preferred pronunciation is part inventor preference, part common sense, part historical similarity, and part phonetics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What dictates how new words should be pronounced?

Usage.  But really, there is no "should" in English.  There is "accepted", "popular", "UK", but there is no "should".  The inventor of a word has zero authority over it.  So being new isn't really relevant.

As the word get's used people will pronounce it as they think best.  Different ways to pronounce the word will compete.  Wars could be fought over how to pronounce it but there still would be no authority.  The spoken word is a fluid thing.  Nailing it down is like nailing jello to a wall.

There are pronunciation guides.  Do not mistake these for authority.  If a biologist hands you a book that explains how fish swim don't think the book controls how fish swim.  At most, it may give you ideas on how you might swim.