# Pronunciation of FEIN as acronym in US

Tags: pronunciation, acronyms

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employer_Identification_Number), FEIN is an abbreviation for Federal Employer Identification Number in the US. Cursory googling shows me that as a name, it could be pronounced *fine* or like *faint*, and in german, it should be pronounced *fine*; however, this doesn't give me a definite answer to whether there is a correct way to pronounce the acronym. I work for an insurance company, and although I've heard both pronunciations from time to time, that doesn't satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: Heh. I'd say "eff-ee-eye-en". I don't know how it would be possible to establish a "correct" pronunciation for it, though. Consider the comments on this similar question: [Pronunciation of file format GIF](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205188)

Comment: Technically speaking, as an abbreviation, it is pronounced "Federal Employer Identification Number". In fact it's at the point that it starts to be pronounced as "fine" or "fain" that it isn't so much an abbreviation anymore but an acronym.

Comment: EIN is pronounced "ee-eye-en", I imagine FEIN would be an extension of that.

Comment: You'll only see *FEIN* used in places like the benefits industry or tax laws; in everyday usage, it's *EIN*, with each letter pronounced as John Feltz notes, and where a distinction is required between federal, state, or other identifiers, in my experience (and I used to work in the benefits industry) people tend to refer to *tax ID* as opposed to EIN, especially at the state level, as states may use other terminology like *seller's permit number* or some such.

Comment: I’d be likely to pronounce it /heɪn/ and just assume it had a _sinn_ missing…